# Substituir Tag por código php

Tags: php

Olá, gostaria de saber se existe um meio de fazer via php o que o sublime text faz com os snippets. Preciso por exemplo substituir uma tag por um código pré-formatado. Tipo:

```
{{repete start}}
  <div class="noticia">Conteúdo</div><br>
{{repete end}}

<!-- isso deverá ser interpretado como abaixo após acessado via web -->
<?php foreach ($noticias as $noticia): ?>
    <?= $noticia['texto'] ?><br>
<?php endforeach ?>

<!-- que no output ficará -->
Conteúdo
Conteúdo
Conteúdo
Conteúdo
Conteúdo
(quantos existirem no banco)
```

É possível ser feito isso utilizando php? Minha idéia é facilitar o trabalho de integradores que utilizam um painel de administração em php que a empresa utiliza. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Não ficou muito claro o que você quer fazer. Qual é exatamente a relação entre os 3 trechos de código?

Comment: O primeiro é a tag que eu quero "criar", pra dizer que aquele bloco irá se repetir. O segundo bloco é o PHP que ele deve executar ao processar isso na página e o terceiro bloco é o output em html do que ele apresenta dessa consulta (levando em conta que a consulta ao banco e select da tabela eu já esteja fazendo acima disso).

Comment: Não é assim tão simples. O que teria o `repete start` ? Como ele saberia que era a tabela noticias ? E como saberia que o conteudo dentro do div era um `campo` da tabela e referente ao repete start ?

Comment: sim tem como e inclusive uso em meu Framework. posso da uma ideia de como fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exemplo de como fazer com PHP:
Ex:

```
{{ variavel }} vira <?php echo $variavel; ?>
```

Código PHP:

```
preg_replace("/({{([ a-zA-Z]*)}})/gm", "<?php echo \$${2}; ?>", $string);
```

Lógico que você fara um fopen para abrir um arquivo e escreve as modificações da view que você quer. Site para testar esse regex: https://regexr.com/